# Aluminium foil sticks to steel ring in Ring Launcher

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, electromagnetic-induction

In [this video](https://youtu.be/T9PflsLZqY8?t=382) (timestamp included in link) a very strange phenomenon is demonstrated. The aluminium foil layer initially shows no reaction to the alternating magnetic field, but as soon as the thick ring is introduced, it swiftly rises and sticks to the thick ring.

I would like to know its explanation.

**My understanding of ring launcher is as follows:** due to *mutual induction* (by the continuously changing vertical component of the magnetic field due to the coil), an induced current is generated in the ring by Faraday’s Law. Now this current, in combination with the *horizontal component of the magnetic field* (due to the same coil), produces a net upward force on the ring. **Please tell me if there are any loose ends in my understanding that need to be fixed.**

I have thought about it and come up with the following:

- the aluminium foil is so thin that its resistance is pretty large so the current is small and the force negligible.
- When the thick ring is introduced, the current in the thick ring is much larger and in the same direction as the aluminium foil, and by analogy of two infinite parallel wires having currents in the same direction, the two rings attract each other.

I would like the community to weigh in on my explanations and perhaps, provide a more solid explanation. (If you include any mathematical explanations, please be sure to keep it in one dimension only. I have no background in multivariable calculus.)

Comment: IDK, maybe haven't pondered it for long enough, but there is no steel ring. All of the rings used in the demo are made of aluminium.

Comment: Ah okay, I will edit it accordingly.

Comment: In regards of what is said in the video your explanation for the resistance of the aluminum foil makes sense, however I disagree with the second part. Lenz's law implies that the magnetic field created by the levitating aluminum ring opposes the magnetic field created by the coil. Thus the induced current in the aluminum foil should decrease.

Comment: I don’t understand. Why is the foil affected?